# How to get ouput from existing group

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, node-editor

i'm new from blender python scripting.

i've create a group node with output, the code are same that:

```
test_group = bpy.data.node_groups.new('testGroup', 'ShaderNodeTree')

# create group outputs
group_outputs = test_group.nodes.new('NodeGroupOutput')
group_outputs.location = (300,0)
test_group.outputs.new('NodeSocketFloat','out_result')

...
test_group.links.new(node_add.outputs[0], group_outputs.inputs['out_result'])
```

All works fine, but how i can get the group_outputs for linking new node if group already exist?

Thank you so much